# how can I determine the token expiration time (Python)

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm been searching (unsuccessfully) for a method to determine the amount of time left on a Oauth2 token.   I've determined that refreshing the token only works after the token has expired (so I can't arbitrary refresh a token).  This leaves me with an issue as I plan on collecting data then in a for loop, writing multiple rows to a google sheet.

My concern is my token will expire during the writes to google sheet.  Unless I can predict when the token will expire this leaves me with two ugly options:

Keep track of the token time

Use Try / exception for each row written.

My test / learning code is below.

Any references would be appreciated.

thanks
Jon

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -- developed with Python 3.4.2
#
# External Resources __________________________________________________________
import time
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import traceback

# Initialize gspread credentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('MyjsonFile.json',scope)
headers = gspread.httpsession.HTTPSession(headers={'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'})
client = gspread.Client(auth=credentials, http_session=headers)
client.login()
workbook = client.open("DataLogger")
wksheet = workbook.get_worksheet(1)

# Start loop ________________________________________________________________
samplecount = 1
while True:
    data_time = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    row_data = [samplecount,data_time]
    if credentials.access_token_expired:
        client.login()        
    wksheet.append_row(row_data)
    print("Number of rows in out worksheet  ",wksheet.row_count)
    print ("samplecount  ", samplecount, row_data)  
    print()
    samplecount += 1
    time.sleep(16*60)
```

Comment: Looks like if you have the access token you can get the lifetime left on it via API request:
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a try.  Question, in your response the code stops at the = sign,  was there supposed to be more?

Comment: You would have to enter the value that you have for your current access token.